# How to set TPanel transparent?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

When placing the `TPanel` component in designer, it seems it can not be made `transparent`? There's an opacity option, but that only deails with animations. I want the panel itself to be fully transparent, so I can see the image underneath. (I want to use the panel as a way of control layout of the controls placed on it)

Comment: Panel.Visible := False;?

Comment: AFAIK: Hides the controls placed on the panel.

Comment: @Tom it hides the panel **and** the child controls

Comment: TPanel has a Windows handle.  Controls with windows handles will fight you to the death to remain non-transparent.  You'll have to use another control -- TShape?  TBevel?  TPaintBox?

Comment: @NickHodges FireMonkey ;)

Comment: As Slomoto's answer, use a TLayout, or set Fill.Color and Stroke.Color to claNull.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use TLayout or TRectangle instead of TPanel.

Comment: Will test later tonight. TLayout sounds promising

Answer (score 1):

You can use almost any object opacity for that, for example:

```
Panel1->Opacity=0.5;
```

Comment: The question states that Opacity is for animations, and that it doesn't work